# How do I target the enter key event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keypress, keycode

I have the following code that works on all keys except enter, shift etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="tmp_post_tag"]').keypress(function(evt){
    alert("hello");
 });
});
```

Why won't it work on enter? which is what I want it to do.
ive tried evt.char, evt.keyCode evt.which but nothing works.

Comment: check `evt.keyCode==13`

Comment: I've tried keyCode. It does not work. This right now alerts me hello on ALL keys except for a few like enter and shift.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is going on, but from reading the documentation at https://api.jquery.com/keypress/ it seems that `.keypress` is temperamental at best, and you're better off using the `keyup` and/or `keydown` events.

Comment: What browser?  That code seems to work in Chrome (including Enter and Shift)

Comment: for `keypress` you should use `evt.which == 13`. for `keyup` or `keydown` use `evt.keyCode == 13`

Comment: Either use `keydown` or `keyup`, since keypress might not support all the keys. After that, enter's keycode is **13**.

Comment: keydown is working on the alert! Thanks make this an answer so I can vote it best answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `KeyDown()` event, it will fire on all special keys including <kbd>enter</kbd>,  <kbd>alt</kbd>,  <kbd>shift</kbd> etc...

Check this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="tmp_post_tag"]').keydown(function(evt){
    console.log('Key pressed : ' + evt.keyCode)
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="input" name="tmp_post_tag" placeholder="press key here" />
```

Comment: Check out this example to get more understanding about key events https://howtodoinjava.com/scripting/jquery/jquery-difference-between-keypress-and-keydown-events/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. the 13 represent the enter key.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name="tmp_post_tag"]').keypress(function(evt){
    if(evt.which == 13) {
        alert("hello");
    }
  });
});
```